# La funcion sumar_votos no me esta sumando los resultados

Tags: python

Esta es la función en donde necesito que sume a las variables que se le pasan por `p`,`o`,`ns` y no lo esta haciendo, pero no puedo retornar varios valores y no se porque no esta sumando a las variables que declaro en la función `main()`

```
def sumar_votos(n,p,o,ns):
    usuarios=n
    print("opciones")
    for i in range(n):
        print("\n ingrese la respuesta del usuario"": ")
        n= int(input())
        if n== 0:
            o  +=1
        elif n==1:
            p  +=1
        elif n==2:
            ns +=1
        else:
            print("VOTO NO VALIDO ")
```

y este es mi main

```
def main ( ):
    cont_p=0
    cont_o=0
    cont_ns=0
    print ("\n\nEn esta encuesta se les preguntará a varias personas: ¿Es usted partidario de la eutanasia?")
    print ("Contestarán 1 si están de acuerdo, 0 si no lo están y 2 si no están seguras.\n")
    a=pide_ent_pos()
    sumar_votos(a,cont_p,cont_o,cont_ns)
    print(cont_p)
    resultados(a,cont_p,cont_o,cont_ns)

    print ("\n\nFin.")
main()
```

Comment: y como sabes que no te esta sumando si nunca haces un `print()` de las variables?

Comment: es que ya lo hice y siguen en 0

Comment: de hecho arriba de resultados esta el print(cont_p) que esta es la variable que necesito que sume :c

Comment: Nop, ese `print(cont_p)` siempre va a imprimir 0 por que tu función `sumar_votos` no retorna ningún valor y tampoco modifica la variable global. Esto no es igual que C donde pasas la dirección de memoria

Comment: rayos, entonces como puedo hacer eso??

Comment: Pon un `print(o,p,ns)` despues de tu `for` y verás que si cambia el valor

Comment: Poniendo un `return o,p,ns` al final de tu función `sumar_votos`

Comment: listo muchas gracias

Comment: de nada, pero al hacer el llamado a tu función debes de guardar los datos obtenidos, lo puedes hacer así `cont_p, cont_o, cont_ns = sumar_votos(a,cont_p,cont_o,cont_ns)`